# How to append data to an array inside an elastic document?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to append data to an array inside my document without success. Here is my code :

```py
doc = {
    "field_1":"1",
    "field_2":"2",
    "tool_result":[{
        "my_array":["data","data2"],
    }]
}
es.index(index="my_index", id=1, document=doc)

update_query = {
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.tool_result.addAll(params.tool_result)",
       "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
            "tool_result": [{"my_array": ["data3", "data4"]}]
        }
    }
}
es.update(index="my_index", id=1, body=update_query)
```

But then the result is :

```json
{
    "field_1":"1",
    "field_2":"2",
    "tool_result":[{
        "my_array":["data","data2"]
    },
    {
        "my_array":["data3","data4"],
    }]
}
```

And I'd like to have instead :

```json
{
    "field_1":"1",
    "field_2":"2",
    "tool_result":[{
        "my_array":["data","data2","data3","data4"],
    }]
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you show your mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, with your code I was able to solve my problem with a more simple query:

```py
update_query = {
    "script": {
       "source": "ctx._source.tool_result[0].my_array.addAll(params.data)",
       "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
            "data": ["data3", "data4"]
        }
    }
}
es.update(index="my_index", id=1, body=update_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
POST test5/_doc
{
  "field_1": "1",
  "field_2": "2",
  "tool_result": [
    {
      "my_array": [
        "data",
        "data2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Query**

Below will give you some idea  how to resolve.

```
POST test5/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": """
              for(int i=0;i<params.data.length;i++)
                {
                  ctx._source.tool_result[0].my_array.add(params.data[i])
                }
                """,
    "params": {
      "data": [
        "data3",
        "data4"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```